# Can a SELECT statement block another SELECT on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, blocking

So the basic question is simple, can a SELECT statement alone block another SELECT statement? My understanding was you needed at least an UPDATE or INSERT for a SELECT to start blocking something because two SELECT will acquire shared locks and those won't block each other. If it is possible, what are the kinds of scenarios that could cause it.

To put this in context, I'm trying to solve some performance problems. I'm not a DBA, I'm just a software engineer having to do a DBA's job, so bear with me. We've recently found there's apparently lot of blocking happening on a database. The way we found out is there's a tool (really a set of scripts/jobs) to monitor the DB named DBWarden, and it compiles some data in a set of tables. For blocking, it uses the following query to insert blocking info into a table every 15 seconds:

```
SELECT
a.spid AS Blocked_SPID,
a.blocked AS Blocking_SPID,
a.loginame AS Blocked_Login,
a.hostname AS Blocked_HostName,
(CAST(a.waittime AS DECIMAL) /1000) AS Blocked_WaitTime_Seconds,
a.lastwaittype AS Blocked_LastWaitType,
a.[status] AS Blocked_Status,
a.[program_name] AS Blocked_Program,
CAST(st1.[text] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as Blocked_SQL_Text,
b.spid AS Offending_SPID,
b.loginame AS Offending_Login,
b.nt_username AS Offending_NTUser,
b.hostname AS Offending_HostName,
b.waittime AS Offending_WaitType,
b.lastwaittype AS Offending_LastWaitType,
b.[status] AS Offending_Status,
b.[program_name] AS Offending_Program,
CAST(st2.text AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as Offending_SQL_Text,
(SELECT name from sys.databases WHERE [database_id] = a.[dbid]) AS [DBName]
FROM master..sysprocesses as a CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (a.sql_handle) as st1
JOIN master..sysprocesses as b CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (b.sql_handle) as st2
ON a.blocked = b.spid
WHERE a.spid > 50 AND a.blocked != 0 AND ((CAST(a.waittime AS DECIMAL) /1000) > 0)
```

What I'm noticing is that both the blocked and offending SQL are almost always SELECT statements. Even if I try to run down a chain of blocks where something blocked something that blocked something, I'd expect to eventually hit an INSERT or UPDATE, but most times I don't, which is what led me to the original question.

Comment: Do you think that  adding some sample SELECT statements that appear to block others might be helpful?

Comment: The SELECT statements can force locking via hints and [they can get blocked for other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999933/how-does-one-select-block-another). You might get better help if you post the results of your diagnostic query (adding wait_resource might be helpful too).